# IBM Worklight: BusyIndicator not showing

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I'm trying to show a BusyIndicator, but when I run the project it doesn't show. 
This is my main.js:

```
var busyInd;

function wlCommonInit() {
    busyInd = new WL.BusyIndicator('content', {text : 'Loading...'}); 
    mostraDialogo(true);
}

function mostraDialogo(on) {
    if (on)
        busyInd.show();
    else
        busyInd.hide();
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Worklight version? Which mobile OS are you trying this on?

Comment: Worklight 6.2. I'm trying this on the Mobile Browser Simulator.

Comment: Mobile Browser Simulator is not a Mobile OS. Which OS are you previewing in the MBS?

Comment: I'm trying to preview it on Android

Comment: Actually I just tried it on the Android Emulator and it does show. It doesn't on the MBS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not have a `content` ID in your HTML.

I've replaced

```
busyInd = new WL.BusyIndicator('content', {text : 'Loading...'});
```

With

```
busyInd = new WL.BusyIndicator(null, {text : 'Loading...'});
```

And I could see the busy indicator.
I also added a DIV with a `content` ID to the HTML, and it worked as well.

When testing in actual devices or simulator/emulator, the ID parameter is not required because it uses a native busy indicator. When testing in the MBS, the ID parameter is required because a web busy indicator is used, and it must be anchored to an existing element (or to null).